# 1 dimensional jigsaw

Tags: jigsaw-puzzle

Can you piece these jigsaw pieces back together again?

```
X...X......X....X..X  
X.X.....X.....X....X  
XX.X...X...X  
X.....X.X...X.....X  
X.X.X.X..X..
```

The solution consists of 25 X's in a row. Where two pieces overlap, X's replace the .'s.

Comment: Nice puzzle. How did you set about looking for a set of pieces which would make a non-trivial puzzle?

Comment: my current [ad hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc) solution is based around another of my puzzles - [Keys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25912/key-and-lock-puzzle). Scrambling this proved very difficult, and I resorted to generating a random puzzle and obscuring the answer by trial and error, all using computers. This has left me with a healthy sense of how to make a solution unique, but as I said, is by no means guaranteed to work. You just reject the rejects I guess.

Comment: If I may, would you mind replacing the `O` by `.`, it would make reading easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is:

> ```
>                    X . . . X . . . . . . X . . . . X . . X       1
>                  X . X . . . . . X . . . . . X . . . . X         2
>          X X . X . . . X . . . X                                 3
>              X . . . . . X . X . . . X . . . . . X               4
>                                    X . X . X . X . . X . .       5
>
>          3 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 1 4 3 2 5 4 5 1 5 2 5 4 1 5 2 1
> ```

Comment: There isn't that much to explain, really: I just pushed the pieces around in a fixed-width text editor until they aligned.

Comment: (I liked the puzzle and I also like the idea of text editors as low-key front end.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Python script which bruteforces the solution. To summarize, it assumes one of the pieces is the right-most, then shifts each remaining piece to the left and checks if it solves the puzzle.

The check is done by treating the strings as binary numbers, performing bit shifts (i.e. multiplying by powers of 2), then check if their sum is equal to $2^{25} - 1$ i.e. the 25-bit number with all 1s.

Note that in the case where the solution consists of multiple pieces aligned at the right-most, the script will think there are multiple solutions, but these can be easily screened out manually.

On my computer this runs for ~0.5s. I imagine this can be optimized if necessary for larger inputs.

```
def f(x):
    return int(x.replace('X', '1').replace('.', '0'), base=2)

def finv(x):
    return "{0:b}".format(x).replace('1', 'X').replace('0', '.')

pieces = [
    f('X...X......X....X..X'),
    f('X.X.....X.....X....X'),
    f('XX.X...X...X'),
    f('X.....X.X...X.....X'),
    f('X.X.X.X..X..')
]

finallen = 25

def piece_len(piece):
    from math import log2, ceil
    return ceil(log2(piece))
    # Alternatively, return len(finv(piece))

for piece in pieces:
    remainingpieces = pieces[:]
    remainingpieces.remove(piece)

    # Assume the current piece is the right-most.
    # The position of each remaining piece is then at most
    # (25 - length of piece) to the left.

    positionstoshift = [0] * len(remainingpieces)
    stoploop = False
    while not stoploop:
        shiftedremainingpieces = []

        for i in range(len(remainingpieces)):
            shiftedremainingpieces.append(
                remainingpieces[i] << positionstoshift[i]
            )

        arithsum = sum(shiftedremainingpieces) + piece

        if arithsum == 2 ** finallen - 1:
            print("Solution found:")
            # Print all pieces with appropriate space padding
            print(" " * (finallen - piece_len(piece)) + finv(piece))
            for i in range(len(remainingpieces)):
                print(" " * (
                    finallen -
                    piece_len(remainingpieces[i]) -
                    positionstoshift[i]
                ) + finv(remainingpieces[i]))
            print("")
            # Terminate the program here if only one solution is needed

        # Increment positionstoshift
        positionstoshift[-1] += 1
        # Loop from the right, carry over as necessary
        for i in range(-1, -len(positionstoshift) - 1, -1):
            if positionstoshift[i] > finallen - piece_len(remainingpieces[i]):
                positionstoshift[i] = 0
                try:
                    positionstoshift[i - 1] += 1
                except IndexError:
                    # Can't carry over, hence reached the end
                    stoploop = True
                    break
```

Output:

> ```
> Solution found:
>      X...X......X....X..X
>     X.X.....X.....X....X
> XX.X...X...X
>   X.....X.X...X.....X
>              X.X.X.X..X..
>
> Solution found:
>              X.X.X.X..X..
>      X...X......X....X..X
>     X.X.....X.....X....X
> XX.X...X...X
>   X.....X.X...X.....X
> ```

Comment: your first 'solution' isn't

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Sorry that was just me messing up the formatting on stackexchange

Comment: okay, but you should have found 120 solutions like this

Comment: @JonMarkPerry How did you arrive at the number 120? I'm struggling to see how my algorithm skipped 118 cases.

Comment: your 2 solutions are permutations of each other by row, and there are 5!=5.4.3.2.1=120 of these.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I am only cherry-picking one row out, but leaving the order of the other rows in tact. Thus, no permutations, only 2 solutions.

Comment: I think what you've done is find the first perm, which is straight from 'pieces', then GO BACK one, and your loop now thinks you are at the end and so terminates. Because the order you slot the pieces together doesn't matter, so the two solutions you have are the same.

Answer (score 0):

A start:

Number the 25 positions $1\dots 25$.

I note that your 2nd piece occupies 4 positions of one parity and 1 of the other. So do your 3rd and 5th pieces. And your 4th occupies 5 positions all of the same parity.